# Different vim colorscheme depending on mode

Tags: vim

I'm often doing the same mistake in vim:

- I forget whether I'm in insert or command mode, then I type in, I get random commands or I modify/delete code, and I have to undo. I do this mistake really too often.

I was thinking of using the `:colorscheme my_color_file` to switch between two color schemes depending if I'm in insert mode or not.

Basically, the `command_color_file.vim`  has a red signature(keywords, tabs) for command mode, while the `insert_color_file.vim` has a green signature.

However I don't find how to perform the `:colorscheme` call any time I enter one mode or another.

Any idea if it is possible to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tested, but try something like this:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * :colorscheme my_color_file_insert
:autocmd InsertLeave * :colorscheme my_color_file_command
```

[This page, about Event-driven scripting in Vim](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-5/index.html) seems to have a good description of how to do it

Comment: it works perfectly !